# How to handle vuex state in nested reusable components?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a complex search page where the user can specify their search with hundreds of different filters. I'm having trouble coming up with a way to streamline everything to use `Vuex`.

For example a section allows to specify multiple min-max range items connected with AND/OR operations.

A pseudo hierarchy would be as follows

```
<parent>
    <multiple-min-max>  
        <number-input :value="greaterEqualValue"> <number-input :value="lessEqualValue"> 
        <select :op="selectedOp"></select>
        <button @click="addNew">
        <button @click="removeCurrent"
    </multiple-min-max>
    ...
    ...
    <multiple-min-max /> another usage for a different thing
</parent>
```

And the  component would be used in a lot of places for different things. 
I don't know how to do the value passing between the top most component to the very bottom and get the values back in the proper store.
There's the obvious way of one-way binding as props and emitting the results back the chain, but for the relatively simple example above, I'd need to emit from both `<number-input>`, then gather everything in `<multiple-min-max>` and emit again to parent.
That seems a *lot* of boilerplate, especially when you have a *lot* of properties to keep track of.

Comment: As you said, use vuex.

Comment: I am in a similar situation, same thoughts. Can you please notice me how you proceeded then?

Comment: @BoteaFlorin I went with passing up values up the chain via events. On the lowest level I did `v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`, then above `v-on:input="$emit('greater-input', $event)"`, and on the top level `v-on:greater-input="updateGreaterEqual($event, index)"`. Similarly for the less-equal side.